# in oracle, is it possible to query columns with same data type

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table which has almost hundred fields. I want to get all the fields which data type is date.  Is it possible in oracle to write such a query  to return fields only contain a certain data type?  Here is my pseudo query:

```
Select * from mytable 
where colum_datatype is date
```

Similarly, I  want to get all fields which is varchar2 type. is it possible to do that? 
I can find all the date fields manually and put them in the query but I just want to know is there another way to do it.
Thank you!

Comment: How will the query be used?  In an application?  Or just for adhoc queries?  Would it be good enough to generate a query and then run it?

Comment: the query will be used in internal applications. we are creating GUIs and scripts to extract some  data from legacy Siebel database. Most siebel tables have lots of fields which really get people lost.

Answer (score 4):

You can query one of the system tables/views to get the list of columns:

```
select column_name
from all_tab_cols
where owner = :owner and table_name = :table and data_type = 'DATE';
```

If you need a one-off solution, just aggregate these and plug into a sql query.  You can construct the entire SQL query:

```
select 'SELECT ' || listagg(column_name, ', ') within group (order by column_id) || ' FROM ' || :table
from all_tab_cols
where owner = :owner and table_name = :table and data_type = 'DATE';
```

You can also put the query into a string and use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`) to run the query.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no such functionality exists in vanilla SQL.  You may be able to simulate such functionality by creating a PL/SQL function that returns a cursor to a dynamically created SQL statement.